# Transport controls for Chromecast via HTTP

Tags: http, chromecast

I was just wondering, can I send transport controls (play, pause, next video) to a chromecast just using HTTP Get/Post from videos posted via another app?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that; the only way to do so is to use the Cast SDK.